# Why does the -f flag of ps not appear to function on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: mac, command-line

I wanted to do a specific `ps` run on a Mac OS X 10.6 machine.  According to `man`, the `-f` flag is available in BSD.  Is it not available in Mac OS X?  If so, why does `man` list it as an option?

I get `illegal option` and it highlights the `-f` flag. I have to `sudo` to get it to execute.

Answer (score 2):

According to `man ps`:

> Display the uid, pid, parent pid, recent CPU usage, process start
>   time, controling tty, elapsed CPU usage, and the associated command.

Works fine on my machine:

```
$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C     STIME TTY           TIME CMD
  501 58104 58103   0   0:00.01 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
```

When getting `illegal option` then, according to [some James Sadler](http://en.newinstance.it/2009/03/29/man-ps-osx-strikes-back/#comment-355228), you need to run `export COMMAND_MODE=unix2003`. Indeed, on my account (admin, but not root), it is set like that. My OS X 10.6 is an upgrade going back to Tiger. In the same post, James also claims:

> I have found that launching `ps` via iTerm would exhibit the problem but not when run via Terminal.app.

Comment: Bizarre.  I get illegal option and it highlights the -f flag.  I have to sudo to get it to execute...is this normal ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Scott `which ps`? Mine is `/bin/ps`.

Comment: @Scott, see my edit.

Comment: ...though, after running `unset COMMAND_MODE` on my machine `ps -f` still runs fine without `sudo`. Also, `sudo bash -c set | grep COMMAND_MODE` yields nothing, though `sudo ps -f` runs fine too. Are you using bash and Terminal, @Scott?

Comment: Hi Arjan!  I am using bash and a 3rd party console app.